# Cannot get JQuery Draggable to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using the same code from the demo website but for whatever reason I cannot get it to work.

Here is the code on my master page:

```
 <link href="JQueryCSS/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"       rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="JQueryUI/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="JQueryCSS/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#draggable").draggable();
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #draggable
    {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
</style>
```

And here is what I have on another page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="ManageDragandDrop.aspx.cs" Inherits="ManageDragandDrop" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>
            Drag me around</p>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

---

#### Fixed

Fixed it, the custom jquery was conflicting with my telerik jquery. Just added these two lines of code to the radscriptmanager and the issue was resolved.

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="MasterScriptManager" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedjQuery="false">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference  Path="~/JQueryUI/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
```

Comment: Please try writing the `$(function () { $("#draggable").draggable(); });` via the console when the page finishes loading. Here is the fiddle: http://jsbin.com/okebaz/1/edit.

Comment: see your console and check all libraries are loaded correctly.

Comment: The console gives me the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'" which is odd because the the method is present in the code

Comment: Seems like jQuery/jQuery UI isn't loaded correctly.
Try the google hosted api to check wheter your local path isn't correct.
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.